# Free reference manager and PDF organizer for Windows

Tags: bibtex, pdf, windows, database

I'm looking for a reliable reference manager and PDF organizer in order to make my research work more efficient and productive.
In particular, I would like the software to help me to export references into the Bibtex format, suggest me new papers on a specific topic (or according to the papers) and automatically extract metadata from PDF files.

Until now, I have found the following softwares:

- Colwiz http://www.colwiz.com/
- Docear http://www.docear.org/
- Mendeley http://www.mendeley.com/
- Qiqqa http://www.qiqqa.com/
- Zotero http://www.zotero.org/
- kBibTeX http://home.gna.org/kbibtex/

In your opinion, which one should be the best combination of simplicity and power?

Comment: This looks borderline for being on-topic to me. Managing BibTeX references is on topic, and we've been asked about that before (JabRef is the obvious cross-platform answer, but there are others). However, the above seems to be at least as much about more general research ideas (suggesting papers, _etc_.): a better fit on the Academia site?

Comment: @JosephWright Borderline on-topic for me. It just asks for a BibTeX manager with advanced features. Mendeley, e.g., does suggest related papers based on keyword tags, I think. There are others that fill BibTeX fields with data extracted from PDFs, but I know no bibliography manager that does all of the above. Vote to reopen.

Comment: For me it seems to be not answerable. What does "more efficient and productive" mean? I guess for everyone something else ...

Comment: How about moving it to Academia exchange?

Comment: Jabref worked for me!